# Using JSON and Ajax together

Tags: ajax, json

I have never used Ajax with JSON. Are there any good resources to look upon?

Comment: google for ajax and jason - 15M hits. I'm pretty sure it's feasible.

Comment: @Mat - and *jason*?  really?  I get a link to some guy named `Jason Ajax Mercer` (actually, Google helpfully corrects my spelling, but ...)  In truth this needs much more context to be useful.  What server side language, what's the application?

Comment: 8-] maybe I typed that comment a bit too quick...

Answer (score 1):

Think of Ajax as a way to send and receive textual content with the server. The format of the messages you send back and forth is up to you. You could use JSON, XML, [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), or whatever else you want.

If you separate these two concerns your problem should be a lot easier to approach.

1. Figure out how to make an Ajax call to your server
2. Figure out how to parse and serialize JSON

If you use a JavaScript framework, like [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) or [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework), both of these things will be handled for you pretty seamlessly with their Ajax [APIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
- http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request